# How to Map String Literal to Destination Property

Tags: automapper, automapper-2

I'd like to be able to do something like this using automapper:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember<d => d.Member, "THIS STRING">();
```

I'd like `d.Member` to always be `"THIS STRING"` and not be mapped from any particular member from the source model. Putting a string field in the source model with `"THIS STRING"` as it's value is also not an option.

Does AutoMapper support these kinds of things in any way?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Member, opt => opt.UseValue<string>("THIS STRING"));
```

Starting with [version 8.0](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html?highlight=value#usevalue) you have to use the following:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Member, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => "THIS STRING"));
```

Comment: Is there good documentation somewhere? All I found was the small wiki on the GitHub page, but that's not much.

Comment: As far as I know, the best documentation is at https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki What's nice about AutoMapper is it's pretty straight forward. opt.MapFrom() to map from properties, opt.UseValue() to use a static value, and opt.ResolveUsing<>() to use a custom resolver.

Comment: The new API replaced this with MapFrom 
https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html?highlight=value#usevalue

`Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Member, opt => opt.MapFrom("THIS STRING"));`

Comment: @WahidBitar Thank you for quoting the source. This is a more accurate example: `.ForMember(dest => dest.Member, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => "THIS STRING"))`

Comment: might as well put it in the form `Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Member, opt => opt.MapFrom(_ => "THIS STRING"));`, "omitting" the src parameter since it's not used